# Monitioring running application

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to monitor all running applications, get events of application main window or child windows. How can I do it?

Comment: Its very HIGH level. But you could use WMI and perf counter classes to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Try **Sysinternals Process Monitor**

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for hooks. There's [an article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997537.aspx) and [entire reference with examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632589%28VS.85%29.aspx) on MSDN about them. You probably want global `WH_GETMESSAGE` hook, since you're trying to capture all window messages.